# The addition of linearly independent vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

If we say that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent vectors in the vector space $V$ over some field $\Bbb F$, then $u+v$ is a linearly independent vector.

Why is this? Isn't it possible for $u+v=0_v$ where $0_v$ is the linearly dependent zero vector?

Comment: But $u+v=0$ contradicts that $u,v$ are linearly independent. So $u+v\neq 0$ and you are done.

Comment: A vector cannot be linearly independent. Linear independence is a property of sets of vectors.

Comment: A vector can be linearly independent...just take the set containing only that vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all by definition, every non-zero vector is linearly independent. Now, if $u, v$ are linearly independent, then there is no way that $u + v=0$, because the coefficients of the linear combination $u+v$ are equal to $1$ for both $u$ and $v$ and so by definition of linear independence we will have $1 \cdot u + 1 \cdot v \neq 0$.